# Wordpress website shows a blank page in IE11 on Windows 7, with no errors in console

Tags: wordpress, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

Wordpress website optimaldesignco.com displays normally in all other browsers, and displays fine in Edge's IE emulation mode for IE11/10/9/8 on a Windows 10 machine, but shows a blank page with no console errors in IE11 on a Win7 machine. (The only way I can test the reported problem for IE11 on Win7 is through browserstack.com, but it has been verified by other Win7 users.)

I have tried changing to a standard 2016 theme, and I have tried deactivating all plugins, but the result is still the same. With no error messages, I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A good wordpress debugging plugin that has helped me solve a number of errors is [Debug Bar](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/). It also helps if you add:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

to the wp-config file. It helps Debug bar to find wordpress query errors.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't able to login in IE11 to activate debug bar, but I will definitely check it out. Sounds like a valuable tool.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the page with Developer Tools already open, and I could see that the source code was only loading up to the WordPress script for emoji settings. I found a [plugin to disable emoji settings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/emoji-settings/), and now the page loads. Seems pretty random, but that's what worked for me.